# Viewing Files in Browser with Symbolic Links

Tags: rhel

Using the Nautilus Browser in Redhat, how do I view the absolute path to a file with a symbolic link? When I select the path bar in the browser, it just shows the symbolic link name, not the absolute path. In Windows, if you click on a shortcut (equivalent to Linux symbolic link), the browser's path bar will resolve to the true location of the file, not the linked location.

Comment: MS-Windows shortcuts are not the same as symlinks. However there are some similarities.

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Something about symlinks, and nautilus, that is clear. But what?

Comment: Is the info that you need in the properties menu (right click → properties)?